# Get rendered result of View Component in derived RazorPage

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I need to get the rendered result of a View Component from within a derived `RazorPage`. In a *.cshtml* file, I can do

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("MyButton", new MyModel())
```

Now, if I have this class which my razor pages inherit from:

```
public class MyRazorPage<TModel> : RazorPage<TModel>
{
    public async Task<HtmlString> GetViewComponentForExample()
    {
        // I cannot access the injected "Component" this way...
        string temp = await Component.InvokeAsync("MyButton", new MyModel()).Result.WriteTo();
        return new HtmlString(temp);
    }
}
```

In the above method `GetViewComponentForExample()` I cannot use the injected Component property. Either how can I access the Component property, or how can I accomplish the above?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is this (ASP .Net Core 2.0)

if you have a Component like this:

```
[ViewComponent(Name = "Cart")]
public class CartViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
    {
         return View("");
    }
}
```

you can call it in a Controller like this

```
public class OtherController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Cart()
    {
        return ViewComponent("Cart");
    }
}
```

This returns a rendered component